# Can we, the user, have a little better control over how we see the sidebar ads?

Tags: feature-request, advertising

I can't believe I'm actually posting this.  You'll see why in a minute.

I'm an aggressive ad ignorer.  Have been my whole life.  I've never used adblock because I don't like to see broken pages, although I have noticed that Google ads now incessantly remind me of everything on Amazon that I've browsed recently.  Thanks, Google.

But I digress.

I use Chrome, which aggressively caches old pages, to the point where I usually have to refresh a Stack page if I use the back button.  The one thing that  *isn't* cached is the sidebar ad, which apparently has some industrial-strength browser cache buster on it.

Invariably, I will see something interesting in the sidebar ad *the moment that I click away from the Stack page that I'm on.*

*[sigh]*

I almost hate myself for asking this, but is there a way to put some left/right buttons or something on the sidebar ad, so that I can find again that interesting thing I was just looking at?

Comment: Wasn't there a page of all the currently running ads somewhere, or am I just imagining things? Maybe it was a feature request...

Comment: Some things, like questions with lulz titles from Gaming, are system-generated.

Comment: I've seen this issue on other sites... mostly news sites, where you see 2 or 3 interesting stories, but when you click on 1 and try to go back, the list of "interesting stories" changes and you can't find the others.

Comment: I have the opposite problem. I keep seeing the same ads over and over. They have a control on them to allow you to say they're too repetitive. I've clicked it hundreds of times but they keep showing the same 3 ads over and over.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know (might still be wrong so comments are welcome) there are four types of advertisements (except for Careers) in Stack Exchange. You can freely "browse" all ads belonging to two of those types.

1. Per site "in house" advertisements, created and posted by ordinary users in the child meta of each site. Users can then vote on each advertisement, and with enough upvotes, the ad will show in the site homepage sidebar. We can see list of those ads, e.g. [Stack Overflow Open Source Advertising](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251196/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2014) or [Gaming/Arqade Community Promotion Ads](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8040/community-promotion-ads-2014).
2. Featured questions from across the network: one of the 100 [Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) is taken in random, given a placeholder according to its parent site and the text is the question title, linking to it. This one is 100% automated as far as I can tell.
3. In house advertisement of the mobile apps or Facebook page of Stack Exchange. Those are cool ads (remember David? :)) but I fear no public list of them exist.
4. External advertisements: bought by whoever got enough money who then send a banner that will link to their website. Those also don't have any public repository that I know of.

I suspect the internal algorithm that choose what we see next is super complicated, so doubt we can have "next/prev" buttons for ads. But one can always hope!